# AppStore iOS WARNING ITMS-9000 "Legacy Language Designator"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I received the following warning while submitting the iOS app at the app store.

> WARNING ITMS-9000 "Legacy Language Designator- The directories located
>   at (my app/English.lproj) use a legacy language designator. Use of the
>   full language name has been deprecated an is not guaranteed to work in
>   future versions of OS."

Has anyone received this and how do I fix?

Comment: You should use `en.lproj` instead of `English.lproj`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rename your file `English.lproj` to `en.lproj`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this we need use ISO-639-1 (two-letter) or ISO-639-2 (three-letter) language codes for localization purposes.

Find all folders in your project with name English.lproj and change them to en.lproj, we should also change all the paths to en.lproj in ProjectName.xcodeproj file by editing in text editor.
For more info follow the process explained in [this link](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=224).

This is applicable for all languages, if you get warning for other languages too.